# TensorFlow OpDef "func" Attribute Type Interpretation

Tags: python, scala, tensorflow

I am currently in the process of implementing a Scala API for TensorFlow and I am using scala.meta to automatically generate the Op creation methods. I am calling `TF_GetAllOpList` from C API to obtain an OpList protocol buffer and I am then parsing that to create the methods.

Each Op can have a set of attributes and each attribute has a type and optionally a default value. I am confused as to what the default value for a `func` attribute should look like and also, how to set that attribute value through the C API when creating the Op (i.e., there is no `TF_SetAttrFunc` function). Could someone provide some clarification with respect to that? Also, a reference to what is currently done when generating the Python API (and to the relevant part of the code that generates the API) would be greatly appreciated.

I am also a bit confused with respect to the `placeholder` attribute type and could use some help with respect to its meaning and use too, but I could create a separate question for that, if necessary.

Thank you!

Comment: Function valued attributes aren't supported in the C API yet. Some languages (such as Go) skip generating functions for those ops at the moment.

Python generates the `GraphDef` proto instead of using the C API functions. This is likely to change in the future since generating the `GraphDef` directly is both more error prone and less performant (since the `GraphDef` has to be serialized and deserialized before the Graph is understood by the runtime).

Out of curiosity, is your Scala API built on top of the [Java API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/java)?

Comment: I see. That's interesting as I thought that the [python_op_gen](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/python_op_gen.cc) files were used to generate python ops that use the C API. I am not building on top of the Java API; I used the same JNI bindings and built a separate Scala library using them. My plan was to write a macro for generating the ops using the C API `TF_GetAllOpList` function, but I have decided to manually port ops for now. That decision is due to the fact that it's easier to group ops and refine their API this way.

Comment: I plan to make a GitHub repository public once I have a good working version, but I could add people interested in collaborating to a private repository in the meantime.